# Assigning references to pointer arrays

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, reference

I am having a following problem understanding the C/C++ syntax.
Suppose we have the following data:

```
int a[3] = {1,3,5};
int b[3] = {2,4,6};
int* p[2];
```

I created an array `p` containing two pointers.

**First question**: why does not the following assignment work:

```
p[0] = &a; p[1] = &b;
```

Since pointers take addresses as their values. For some reason `p[0] = a; p[1] = b;` works though.

**Second question:** since p[0] now points to `a`, why does not `*(*(p[0]))[0]` work? How should I get the value from a pointer referencing a at some index?

**Background:** I am having these problem because I am trying to naturally extend the syntax with scalars to arrays, where the following syntax would work:

```
  double a = 3;
  double* p = &a;
```

and *p gives the value, whereas p gives the address.

Comment: `a` is kinda `int*` so `p[0] = a` will work.

Comment: The syntax for declaring a pointer to an array is `int (*p)[3]`. The syntax for declaring an array of pointers to arrays is `int (*p[2])[3]`.

Comment: Please decide whether you want a C or a C++ answer. In many ways both languages diverge and often warrant different answers as there is no "correct one".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First question: why does not the following assignment work:

```cpp
p[0] = &a; p[1] = &b;
```

Your using a single `int*` variable from an array of pointers, what would you expect it to point to? Address of an array as a whole or a particular element? Of course a singular value, for which `p[index]` can be only assigned to a single variable, such as `a[index]` in your case. For example this would work:

```cpp
p[0] = &a[0];
// cout<<*p[0]; would yield a[0] or 1.
```

> Second question: since p[0] now points to a, why does not `*(*(p[0]))[0]` work? How should I get the value from a pointer referencing a at some index?

You are dereferencing the pointer (should have referenced back with `&`). Use `p[0][index]` to reference `a` at required index.

Answer (score 3):

There are different types of pointers. `&a` is a pointer to an array of 3 `int`s. `p[0]` is a pointer to a single `int`. They are not compatible. Meanwhile an array can decay to a pointer to the first element, so `p[0] = a` makes `p[0]` point to the first element of `a`. You can access elements in `a` by applying an offset to the pointer to the first element using `*(p[0] + i)` which is equivalent to `p[0][i]`.

Answer (score 1):

The array a, when used in this context, behaves as if it is a pointer to its first array element.

So naked a behaves like &a[0]

whereas &a is the address of the local array variable. So &a is an address of an array.

Comment: `a` is not an address, it is not a pointer. `a` is an array. It is true that here and in many contexts `a` decays to a pointer. But `a` is not a pointer.

Comment: Perhaps I oversimplified for the sake of the OP.

Comment: I strongly feel that the "an array is a pointer" simplification does more bad than good, especially on the long run. Plus, it is not that difficult to explain and understand that arrays are arrays and in some contexts they decay to a pointer to the first element of the array.

Comment: Edited the wording to be a bit more guarded, but tried not complicate it

Comment: The edit is good. You answer is correct. Except that in `&a` `a` doesn't decay so the the type of `&a` is `int (*)[3]` i.e. pointer to an array, not pointer to pointer. I've edited that part and removed my downvote